# Download issues with Riak Kv from given url

Tags: riak

I want to download riak Kv, but not able to download it. from where i can download this.

achually i tried with this link `https://riak.docs.hw.ag/riak/kv/2.2.3/downloads/`

Suggent me how we download this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as you probably know basho, the ex owner of riak, get in trouble and bet365 take the lead. There is a very active community around riak and you can find all the bin that you are looking for here https://files-source.tiot.jp/riak/